# Trying to use append user input into list

Tags: python, string, attributes, append

I'm learning python at the moment so i am facing following error in my code please help me to address this isssue.

```
while True:
    user_action = input("Type add, show, complete, edit or exit:")
    user_action = user_action.strip()

    match user_action:
        case 'add':
            todo = input('Enter new todo')
            file = open('todos.txt', 'r')
            todos = file.readline()
            file.close()


            todos.append(todo)

            file = open('todos.txt', 'w')
            file.writelines(todos)
            file.close()

        case 'show':
            for index, item in enumerate(todos):
                row = f"{index + 1}-{item.title()}"
                print(row)
        case 'edit':
            number = int(input("Enter the number you want to edit:"))
            number = number - 1
            new_todo = input("Enter new list:")
            todos[number] = new_todo
        case 'complete':
            number = int(input("Enter what number from the list want to remove:"))
            todos.pop(number - 1)
        case 'exit':
            print('Goodbye see you later!')
            break
```

code above showing the following error.

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\python\app1\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    todos.append(todo)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`
```

I want to add user input in the list

Answer (score 0):

you can use operator (+) to concatenate strings together (see examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_concatenation.asp))
try using the following for your problem:

```
todos = todos+' '+todo
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You are using readline(), which returns thr first line of the file. Consider using readlines() instead, which returns a **list** of all of the lines in the file.

Example:

```py
todos = file.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only append to a list not string. What you should do is to [**split**](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/split) the todos by a newline to get list of todos then you can append. And when writing to the file you [**join**](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join) the list of todos back to string.

```py
...
todos = file.readline()
file.close()

todo_list = todos.split("\n")
todo_list.append(todo)
todos = "\n".join(todo_list)

file = open('todos.txt', 'w')
file.writelines(todos)
file.close()
...
```

You can also use an `f-string` to [**concatenate**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) if you want to avoid the append method.
Example:

```
todos = file.readline()
file.close()

todos = f"{todos}\n{todo}"

file = open('todos.txt', 'w')
file.writelines(todos)
file.close()
```